# How do you get errors in the ModelState, for a particular property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I'm encountering the following issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4989, and based on 'rsheptolut' comment on Sep 12, 2016, he found this workaround (pasted for convenience):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" asp-antiforgery="true">
  <fieldset>
    // All of this instead of @Html.ValidationSummary(false) due to a bug in ASP.NET Core 1.0
    @if (!@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = ViewData.ModelState.Values.Select(item => item.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.ErrorMessage).Where(item => item != null);
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <span>@Localizer["There are problems with your input:"]</span>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var error in errors)
                {
                    <li>@error</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    }

    // Some actual fields. Don't forget validation messages for fields if you need them (@Html.ValidationMessage)
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

My issue is with the LINQ to get the `errors` variable. I want to filter these by the name of the property, so the list of errors listed under my file uploads element will not contain errors from other elements on the page. I want to do something like this:

```
ViewData.ModelState.Values.Where(item => item.Key == "Images").Select...;
```

However, LINQ doesn't find Key as a valid property of the ModelStateEntry class. Fair enough. But why then, when add a quick watch to `ViewData.ModelState.Values`, does the Key property show up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you want the error(s) for proeprty `Name`

```
string propertyName = "Name";
```

To get the first error (which is what will be displayed when using `@Html.ValidationSummary()`, you can use

```
string error = ViewData.ModelState.Keys.Where(k => k == propertyName)
    .Select(k => ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage).First();
```

or to get all errors for a property

```
IEnumerable<string> errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => k == propertyName)
    .Select(k => ModelState[k].Errors).First().Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
```

and use your `foreach` as noted in the question

Comment: Thank you! The last bit what exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: How do I get the property(s) of the model due to which the `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`?

Comment: @barnes. You could use `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });` which will list all properties that have an error, and the associated error message (but you really should be asking a new question)

Comment: Looking at code for Html.ValidationSummary() and I dug down into here: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs,941 but I don't see code that only takes first item.  Am I looking in the wrong spot or have things changed in last 3 years?